# Getting 1064 error while creating mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create mysql trigger but getting an error

> Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use  near '' at line 14

Here is my sql script

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_account_balance_after_transfer` AFTER INSERT ON `balance_transfer`
 FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN
    IF(NEW.from_account_type='CUSTOMER') THEN
        UPDATE customer c SET c.balance = c.balance-NEW.amount WHERE c.customer_id= NEW.from_account_id;
    ELSE IF(NEW.from_account_type='Vendor') THEN
        UPDATE vendor V SET v.balance = v.balance-NEW.amount WHERE v.vendor= NEW.from_account_id;
    END IF;
    IF(NEW.to_account_type='VENDOR') THEN
        UPDATE customer c SET c.balance = c.balance+NEW.amount WHERE c.customer_id= NEW.to_account_id;
    ELSE IF(NEW.to_account_type='Vendor') THEN
        UPDATE vendor V SET v.balance = v.balance+NEW.amount WHERE v.vendor= NEW.to_account_id;
    END IF;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove space between `ELSE` and `IF`. It should be `ELSEIF` as below.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_account_balance_after_transfer` AFTER INSERT ON `balance_transfer`
 FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN
    IF(NEW.from_account_type='CUSTOMER') THEN
        UPDATE customer c SET c.balance = c.balance-NEW.amount WHERE c.customer_id= NEW.from_account_id;
    ELSEIF(NEW.from_account_type='Vendor') THEN
        UPDATE vendor V SET v.balance = v.balance-NEW.amount WHERE v.vendor= NEW.from_account_id;
    END IF;
    IF(NEW.to_account_type='VENDOR') THEN
        UPDATE customer c SET c.balance = c.balance+NEW.amount WHERE c.customer_id= NEW.to_account_id;
    ELSEIF(NEW.to_account_type='Vendor') THEN
        UPDATE vendor V SET v.balance = v.balance+NEW.amount WHERE v.vendor= NEW.to_account_id;
    END IF;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

MySQL **[IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)** Syntax

Check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/XUHH71635)**

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, actually i have removed those spaces earlier, then later I update sql statement and copied old code from notepad. 
Thanks btw.. :)